# Relating input to output with Neural Network and optimizing inputs using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: matlab, optimization, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm currently doing proces optimization for laser cutting - in MATLAB. I am trying to relate the process parameters with the cutting quality such as e.g.:

Inputs *(Process parameters)*

1. Cutting speed
2. Laser power
3. Assist gas pressure

Outputs *(Quality parameters)*

1. Cutting depth
2. Cutting width

I am first training a Neural Network model in order to predict the cutting quality from the process parameters.

```
[inputs,targets] = lasercutting_dataset;

nLayers = 2;            % number of hidden layers
trainFcn = 'trainlm';   % Levenberg Marqhart training function

net = fitnet(nLayers,trainFcn);
```

This works fine, and for now I am not interested in the performance.

Next I want to optimize (maximize) the input parameter cutting speed using Genetic Algorithm. This means my fitness function (object function) is 1/cutting speed.

I have made a matlab function for my fitness function:

```
function y = fitness(x)

    y = 1/x(1);

end
```

Next i set the number of design variables and their upper and lower bounds:

```
nvars = 3;    % Number of variables
LB = [130 8130  4470];   % Lower bound
UB = [175 11255 8250];  % Upper bound
```

Next i define my constraint on the cutting width (I will be adding one for the depth as well).

```
function [c, ceq] = constraints(net,x) 

    outs = net(x)

    c = [outs(2)+495; outs(2)-505];
    % 495 <= outs
    % outs <= 505

    ceq = [];

end
```

This function is the one causing problems!

Lastly I make handles for the functions and start the optimization:

```
[x,fval] = ga(@fitness_func,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,@(x) ConstraintFunction(net,x));
```

I have tried defining an input vector for the neural network (net()) inside the constraints function which was independent of x - this worked fine:

```
dummyInput = [value; value; value];
net(dummyInput);
```

I'm among others getting the error, that my functions constraints is not getting enough input parameters.

The problem seems to be something with passing the dynamically changing "x" to a function and then predicting on it, using the output for a set of dynamically changing constraints.

Any ideas as to what might be the problem?

I've been using [THIS](http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-EFLUUB/?solution=1-EFLUUB) and [THIS](http://www.mathworks.se/help/gads/examples/constrained-minimization-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html) for inspiration.

Any help is appreciated - sorry for the long questiong. I have several articles on the matter - none of which explains the problem in matlab, merely the procedure.

Comment: MATLAB is designed to handle variables having such "dynamic" behaviour. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By maximizing 1/x, this will give you the slowest cutting speed for which the constraints hold. I assume you want to maximize the cutting speed, not minimize it.

Also your constraint function is not really valid. Constraints need to be given in the form `x <= 0`. So if the outputs should be bounded, the constraints become `x >= 495 <=> 0 >= 495 - x` and `x <= 505 <=> x - 505 <= 0`

In your function you however write `c = [outs(2)+495; outs(2)-505];` which should then rather be `c = [495 - outs(2); outs(2) - 505]`.

Regarding the extra parameter in your function, maybe this doc can be of [help](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html).

Comment: Duly noted. I realized that I had made the constraints incorrectly when I started optimizing. It works now, I merely used the function handle incorrectly.

Comment: Okay, so if this answer is sufficient for the question maybe you can accept it as well.